# php chr() with numbers over 255

Tags: php

I have been using the php `chr()` function, and I had the idea of printing every character by using a variable that starts at one, prints of the ASCII value, and then increments it and then repeats this action. This is what I have done:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while($i<255)
{
    echo chr($i)."\n";
    $i++;
}
?>
```

That successfully works. It prints out every ASCII value, but I have noticed that if I use something with a value over 255 like this:

```
chr(300);
```

it will just start going through from the start again as soon as it is over 255. So, I was wondering if there was anyway to make php print two characters if it is over 255 (eg. when you use the number 300 it places the character 255 followed by character 45). Is this possible? If so, how would I do it?

Comment: The goal is not clear. What you do expect to get if you feed it 300? Character 255 followed by character 45? The other way round? A multi-byte Unicode character?

Comment: Hey, if someone answered your question, mark it as beset answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. It's and infinite loop and it is pointless but it should work.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$string = '';

do
{
    if($i<255) {
      echo $string . chr($i)."\n";
      $i++;
    } else {
      $string .= chr(255);
      $i = 0;
    }
}
while($i<255);
?>
```

And here it is with limit for the loop:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
$limit = 255*4;

$string = '';

do
{
    $j++;
    if($i<255) {
      echo $string . chr($i)."\n";
      $i++;
    } else {
      $string .= chr(255);
      $i = 0;
    }
}
while($i<255 && $j<$limit);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here is a recursive solution:

```
<?php

function char($i, $max = 255) {
    if ($i > $max) {
        return char($max, $max) . char($i-$max, $max);
    }
    return chr($i);
}

echo char(365, 66);
echo "\n";
echo char(1365, 122);
echo "\n";
```

Don't provide a second argument to default to 255.

Example output:

```
BBBBB#
yyyyyyyyyyy"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically what you're looking for (but it makes no sense):

```
$char = (int) X;
```

The input variable. It's an integer. You want to do something until, so we take a `while` loop:

```
while ($char >= 0) {
```

While `$char` is greater or equal zero there is something to do. In case it's as well below 255, we output it and break the loop:

```
    if ($char < 256) {
        echo chr($char);
        break;
    }
```

Fine. Now comes the crazy part. As it can be larger than 256 we just output:

```
    echo chr(255);
```

Always? Yes, always. And as we have outputted it, we substract it from the value

```
    $char -= 256;
```

Then we try again with the loop:

```
}
```

As you can see this makes so much no sense at all:

```
$char = (int) X;
while ($char >= 0) {
    if ($char < 256) {
        echo chr($char);
        break;
    }
    echo chr(255);
    $char -= 256;
}
```

It will just prefix some modulo value with `chr(255)` if greater than 255. For what? For `chr(255)` prefixing?